# Scala: II have a Avro file with Body as Binary, unable to decode it to string, as I want to parse this string toJson

Tags: json, scala, avro

I am an Avro file from Event hub capture which has a body property, it has my string serialized in binary format, I want to decode it to string so that I can further parse it into JSON.

Any help appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the "body" field?

Answer (score 1):

Once you read your message off the event hub, I'm assuming you have a GenericRecord. The GenericRecord's `.get` will return an `AnyRef` that you can convert to an `Array[Byte]`. This byte array and can be use to instantiate your json string.

```
val bodyBytes = record.get("body").asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]
val body = new String(bodyBytes) // assumes UTF-8 encoding
```

Now that you have your `body` in the form of a JSON string, you can deserialize the JSON to a Map or other type.

Here is the test I created:

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class AvroSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  import org.apache.avro.Schema
  import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  val schemaString =
    """
         {
         "type": "record",
         "namespace": "com.example",
         "name": "EventMessage",
         "fields": [
          { "name": "body", "type": "string" }
         ]
         }
      """

  val schema: Schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString)
  val record = new GenericData.Record(schema)

  record.put("body",
    """
        {
          "user": "Ankit Gupt",
          "languages": ["scala", "java", "js"]
        }
      """.getBytes)


  "Avro" should "decode bytes and parse json" in {

    // get field, convert raw byte string and decode
    val bodyBytes = record.get("body").asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]
    val bodyStr = new String(bodyBytes)

    // parse json and extract
    // implicit formats used by json4s
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val bodyMap = parse(bodyStr).extract[Map[String, Any]]
    bodyMap("user") should equal("Ankit Gupt")
  }

}
```

Comment: Here the problem is the JSON I get is in binary\ serialized Avro format stored in a dataframe, to use getBytes on it first I need to decode it and then getBytes, that is where I am facing challenge

Comment: +--------------+------+--------------------+----------------+----------+--------------------+
|SequenceNumber|Offset|     EnqueuedTimeUtc|SystemProperties|Properties|                Body|
+--------------+------+--------------------+----------------+----------+--------------------+
|            10|  6480|10/25/2018 7:15:4...|           Map()|     Map()|[7B 0D 0A 20 20

Comment: "[7B 0D" this is the serialized Avro data which I want to decode.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parse Body of AVRO file
// 1. Select Body column in Binary Format
// 2. Cast the Cody Column as String
// 3. Use map function of RDD to convert each element in list to Sting format
val bodyRDD = df.select(col("Body").cast("string")).rdd.map(x=>x(0).toString())

// Read parsed string in JSON format
val data = spark.read.json(bodyRDD)
```

Comment: Where did you defined col?